# É possível abrir um form com um usuário comum e outro como administrador na mesma aplicação?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, windows, vb.net

Tenho um programa que em determinadas partes precisa ser executado como administrador, já em outras precisa ser executado como usuário comum .
Exemplo:

```
configuracoes.Show() 'Esse será executado como usuário comum'
suporte.Show() 'Esse como administrador'
```

O ideal seria como fazer isso em **vb.net**, mas se for em **C#** também serve.

Comment: acredito que não, porque o processo que é elevado. Isso é característico do sistema operacional e independe de linguagem, etc

Comment: Só por curiosidade, qual o objetivo de abrir um ecrã com previlégios de Administrador e outros não?

Comment: O configuracoes e o suporte são processos diferentes, caso sejam vc pode especificar no manifest a necessidade da execução como administrador do sistema `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`.

Comment: configurações e suporte estão no mesmo .exe acho que mudar o manifesto vai alterar o programa todo e não só determinadas partes.

Comment: João é porque em determinadas partes do meu programa ele meche com processos do windows  o que requer privilegios de adm, ja outra parte (nas configurações) o usuario precisa indicar a localização de um determinado arquivo.

Até ai tudo ok, só que esse arquivo esta em uma pasta mapeada pelo usuario normal, e como o usuario administrador não tem essa pasta de rede mapeada não aparece para o usuario, porque é como se o administrador estivesse logado na conta dele e não o usuario. eu demorei bastante pra descobrir isso

Answer (score 0):

Depende! Você se quer abrir no mesmo processo ou em processos separados.
Se você deseja abrir no mesmo processo, a resposta é não.
Se você quer abrir em em processos separados sim.

[Link de um tutorial sobre](http://www.macoratti.net/14/08/vbn_eadm1.htm)

Comment: Olá @Danrley. Evite colocar apenas o _link_ para a resposta. Coloque código que suporte a sua resposta e que possa ajudar na solução.

Comment: daqui a pouco eu edito, só um momento.